# Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian

[image]

Hello,
I am totally confused in deriving bayes classifier. Normally, I would be given a problem like the one above so that i get the number of red dots and green dots and i calculate the feature distribution F(X). But how can i do the same when i get a binary distribution graph like below:

[image]

Here class variable Y∈(red,blue) and feature variable X∈(-4,4). The joint distribution of P(X,Y) are shown in the plot. (P(X,Y=blue) and P(X,Y=red)). Now, how can i derive and plot the feature distribution P(X).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bayesian classification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047494/bayesian-classification)

Comment: Please, **don't ask the same question twice**.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, it's not hard to see that `P(X)` depends on `P(Y)`. For example, if `P(Y=blue) = 1`, then

```
P(X) = P(X | Y=blue)
```

(In words, if you know Y is blue, then the probability density plot for `X` is given by the blue plot you posted).
And similarly, if `P(Y=red) = 1`, then

```
P(X) = P(X | Y=red)
```

Since `Y` is a binary class variable, its distribution can be specified by a single probability, `P(Y=blue) = p`, since that would imply `P(Y=red) = q = 1-p`.

Given the result above, it's not hard to believe that if `P(Y=blue)` were something other than 1, that `P(X)` should be some mixture of `P(X | Y=blue)` and `P(X | Y=red)`. In fact,
it makes sense that it should be a linear mixture:

```
P(X) = p * P(X | Y=blue) + q * P(X | Y=red)
```

You can prove that using [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27%5ftheorem):

```
P(X) * P(Y=blue | X) = P(Y=blue) * P(X | Y=blue)

P(X) * P(Y=red | X) = P(Y=red) * P(X | Y=red)
```

Adding the two lines together,

```
P(X) * [P(Y=blue | X) + P(Y=red | X)] = P(Y=blue) * P(X | Y=blue) + P(Y=red) * P(X | Y=red)
```

Since `Y` must be either red or blue, `P(Y=blue | X) + P(Y=red | X)` must equal 1, so the bracketed expression drops out and you get:

```
P(X) = P(Y=blue) * P(X | Y=blue) + P(Y=red) * P(X | Y=red)

P(X) = p * P(X | Y=blue) + q * P(X | Y=red)
```

Comment: Hi..thank u so much for ur reply... but how will u plot P(X) with this information

Comment: First you need to know `p`, the probability that `Y=blue`. Then you compute the linear combination of the blue and red curves, weighted by `p` and `q`. If you don't know `p` then I think the problem as stated is not well-defined.